# Digest authentication not working on IE8, Firefox and Chrome are fine

Tags: c#, firefox, internet-explorer-8, google-chrome, digest-authentication

I have a website with digest authentication required and when I browse it with IE8, it gives me 401 even the password is correct. Firefox and Chrome works correctly. I checked the authorization headers with Fiddler, everything seems fine. Can you give me any hints on the problem?

p.s. Additionally I do have the same problem with implementing digest authentication in C#, I don't know these two are related.

Comment: Here's the server header.

Server: Apache/2.2.13 (FreeBSD) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8e DAV/2 mod_wsgi/2.8 Python/2.5.4 PHP/5.2.12 with Suhosin-Patch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.  In my case, I was requiring digest authentication for my entire site, using directives in either "<Directory />" or "<Location />".  Either way works for Firefox and Safari on Mac, PC, and iOS.  Unfortunately, IE8 seems to have trouble with this.  After trying several other changes, I finally found that if I only require authentication on a subdirectory (e.g.  "<Location /private>"), and move my content into the protected directory, IE8 started working.  I went back and forth a few times, changing only this attribute, to confirm that this is the critical difference.

Incidentally, it's worth noting that a tcpdump showed that IE8 wasn't even *trying* to send a digest authentication.  It presented the auth dialog box, took my username and password, then sent a normal GET request with no authentication info.

Are (were) you protecting the entire content tree?

I'm not sure why IE8 (and only IE8) cares about this distinction, but this is what I found.

In searching for a solution to the problem, yours was the only mention that seemed relevant, and I could find no answer posted on the net.  This leads me to believe that either no one tries to configure Digest authentication in this way, or most people just give up and use Firefox (or some other non-MS browser)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this problem and this was the only mention of it on the net. In Digest Access Authentication the sequence of events that take place is.

1. GET on /url
2. 401 with a WWW-Authenticate header
   This pops up the login dialog on your browser. After you enter your credentials.
3. GET on /url along with the Authorization header.
4. 200 OK  (If everything goes well).

This works fine for Firefox and Chrome but was not working fully for IE8.

By fully I mean, that if I did a GET on a virtual location on the server it worked, but it did not work when I did a GET on a static file. In the case for a static file I was prompted for a login again and again.

After using a sniffer I found out that in the case of requesting a virtual location the sequence of events happened as mentioned above, but when I requested a static file the sequence was as follows:

1. GET on /url
2. 401 with a WWW-Authenticate header
   This pops up the login dialog on your browser. After you enter your credentials.
3. GET on /url        (WITHOUT THE Authorization header)
4. 401 Un-Authorized.

Basically when it was a static file, it took the username and password but never sent it across in the Authorization header. Server not getting this header responded with 401 which again prompted the login.

To make IE8 work properly you have to fool it in thinking that this is not a static file, but is a virtual location. For me, it was easy as I had access the server's source code. I really don't know how to do it, if you don't have access to it.

If you have requested a virtual location.
1. GET /virtual_location
2. 401 with WWW-Authenticate header which will look something like

WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="validusers@robapi.abb", domain="127.0.0.1:80", qop="auth", nonce="9001cd8a528157344c6373810637d030", opaque="", algorithm="MD5", stale="FALSE"

Notice the opapue parameter is an empty string.

On the other hand if you requested a static-file
1. GET /staticfile.txt
2. 401 with WWW-Authenticate header which will look something like

WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="validusers@robapi.abb", domain="127.0.0.1:80", qop="auth", nonce="81bd1ca10ed6314570b7362484f0fd31", opaque="0-1c5-4f7f4c1e", algorithm="MD5", stale="FALSE"

Here the opaque parameter is a non empty string.

Hence, if you an ensure that the opaque parameter is always an empty string, IE8 will consider it as a virtual location and the request will go through normally. Since I had access to the the server's code I was able to do this.

Hope this is of any help.

Regards,
Satya Sidhu

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I'm definitely having the same problem.  I have two virtual hosts, both using digest authentication.  On one site I am trying to protect the entire site (i.e. ) and it works in all browsers I have tried *except* IE8.  On the other site, I'm only protecting a subdirectory, and that works fine in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried to use the digest authentication for the whole vhost. But the following configuration did not work on IE.

```
<Location />
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "Login"
    AuthDigestDomain /
    AuthUserFile /path/to/.htdigest
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

The workaround in http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2013-January/131225.html worked well:

```
ErrorDocument 401 "some random text"
```

A better solution is to exclude the apache error pages that are normally located at /error/.*

```
e.g.
Alias /error/ "/usr/share/apache2/error/"
```

The following configuration worked well for me (see also https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10932#c5):

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?!error/)">
    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "Login"
    AuthDigestDomain /
    AuthUserFile /path/to/.htdigest
    Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```